# add string to the end of the Model.Variable Name while loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible in razor to add to the end of a model.variable.

For example:

```
@for (var a = 1; 6 > a; a++)
       {
       @if (@Model.ContentSection+{a} != null)
       {
```

Bit of a background:
I have multiple content boxes and instead of copy and pasting the html 5 times I want to run a for loop to create the div's if there is content in one of the ContentSection.

in My VM I have ContentSection1, ContentSection2 etc.

What I want to do is add the current value of a to the end of the Model.ContentSection so when it goes through its adding the content from say @Model.ContentSection2

Thanks

Comment: You may consider to have `ContentSections[]` instead of `ContentSection`. There are alternatives (Reflection or `this[index]` in your model, for example) but...

Comment: Your view model should have a collection of `ContentSection`, not `ContentSection1`, `ContentSection2` etc.

Comment: BTW, it seems you have an infinite loop here. Shouldn't `--a` be `a++`?

Comment: Corrected infinite loop.

Comment: @StephenMuecke the reason behind not having a collection is there are separate editors and its not formed as part of a list

Comment: Do you mean separate `EditorTemplates`?

Comment: Numbered properties are a sure sign of a crippled design. Are you sure you don't want a `List<ContentSection>` property instead?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - So i have 5 different rich text editor in the document type in umbraco each has its own content. I logically went down a numbered route just because they are not a list (in that im not selecting multiple items that are similar). So its like Section 1 Content (RichTextEditor) > Section1Content in the VM > display the content in this section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. First you shoul add the followinf code to your class model (this will give access to properties of your model by Key (for example Model["Property1"]):

```
public object this[string propertyName]
{
   get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null); }
   set { this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value, null); }
}
```

Then in razor (inside you loop):

```
@if(Model["ContentSection" + a.ToString()] != null)
{
    Model["ContentSection" + a.ToString()]
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly - the only thing is that I have one Model item which has a child model so @Model["SectionRight" + a.ToString()].Url doesn't currently work - what is the correct syntax?

Comment: after `@Model["SectionRight" + a.ToString()].Url`, cast it. Something like: `(ChildClass)Model["SectionRight" + a.ToString()].Url`

Comment: Typically I'd do Model.SectionRight1.Url (SectionRight1 being a public Image and Image being a cs with a URL variable).
Error I'm getting is cannot convert method group Url to Non-delegate type 'object'

Comment: Do i need to be including the relevant ChildClass or just copy in what you wrote?

Comment: Something like this - maybe the full namespace/path of class will be required to recognize it: `(App.Models.Image)Model["SectionRight" + a.ToString()].Url`

Comment: Figured it out its @(((TSW.Model.Image)Model["SectionRight" + a.ToString()]).Url) - Thanks for your help!